# Index Lifecycle policy for deleting old indices

Tags: elasticsearch, elk

I've read the following tutorial:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/getting-started-index-lifecycle-management.html

After following its stages for several times, I'm still stuck getting the same errors.
I would like to automatically delete old indices, that are at a certain age.

I have several instances on AWS, each instance is writing to its own index on elastic-search e.g.:
index name -

```
filebeat-log-centralization-ds-test-2020.08.09
```

which is mapped to an index template

```
{
  "filebeat-template" : {
    "order" : 0,
    "index_patterns" : [
      "filebeat-*"
    ],
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "lifecycle" : {
          "name" : "logs-deletion-policy",
          "rollover_alias" : "filebeat"
        },
        "number_of_shards" : "1",
        "number_of_replicas" : "0"
      }
    },
    "mappings" : {
      "_meta" : { },
      "_source" : { },
      "properties" : { /*** some mappings ***/
    "aliases" : { }
  }
}
```

ILM policy :

```
PUT _ilm/policy/logs-deletion-policy
{
  "policy": {
    "phases": {
      "hot": {                      
        "actions": {
          "rollover": {
            "max_size": "50GB",     
            "max_age": "1m"
          }
        }
      },
      "delete": {
        "min_age": "0d",           
        "actions": {
          "delete": {}              
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've bootstrapped the rollover alias index :

```
PUT filebeat-000001
{
  "aliases": {
    "filebeat": {
      "is_write_index": true
    }
  }
}
```

The filebeat-0000N index (rollover alias index i've just created) is rolling over and being deleted fine,
however `"filebeat-log-centralization-ds-test-2020.08.09"` is showing an error :

```
illegal_argument_exception: index.lifecycle.rollover_alias [filebeat] 
does not point to index [filebeat-log-centralization-ds-test-2020.08.09]
```

I Have no idea what am I doing wrong, and tried to repeat the tutorial with no success.
What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

I've tried adding the filebeat alias to the index template.

```
GET /filebeat-log-centralization-ds-test-2020.08.09/_alias/
{
  "filebeat-log-centralization-ds-test-2020.08.09" : {
    "aliases" : {
      "filebeat" : { }
    }
  }
}
```

which results in an error for the `filebeat-log-centralization-ds-test-2020.08.09` index

`illegal_argument_exception: Rollover alias [filebeat] can point to multiple indices, found duplicated alias [[filebeat]] in index template [filebeat-template]`

Comment: Sure, but the problem isn't solved yet. ILM still shows errors. can't manage to find a solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could not fix this issue, but did solve it using [curator](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/5.8/index.html), since my main goal was to delete old indices.

Create a file called `config.yml`

```
client:
  hosts:
    - 127.0.0.1
  port: 9200
  url_prefix:
  use_ssl: False
  certificate:
  client_cert:
  client_key:
  ssl_no_validate: False
  http_auth: username:password
  timeout: 30
  master_only: False

logging:
  loglevel: INFO
  logfile:  /var/log/curator/curator.log
  logformat: default
  blacklist: ['elasticsearch', 'urllib3']
```

Curator needs an action file. Create a file called `delete_indices.yml`

```
actions:
  1:
    action: delete_indices
    description: >-
      Delete indices with age greater than 4 days(based on index name), for filebeat-*
      prefixed indices.
    options:
      ignore_empty_list: True
      disable_action: False
    filters:
    - filtertype: pattern
      kind: prefix
      value: filebeat-
    - filtertype: age
      source: creation_date
      direction: older
      unit: days
      unit_count: 4
```

Above config deletes all indices with age greater than 4 days

Now you can run it using the following command -

```
curator --config config.yml delete_indices.yml
```

Since my configuration required automatically deleting old indices, I'm running it using `crontab`.

Run

```
crontab -e
```

This will open your personal crontab (cron configuration file).

Add the following code-

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/curator --config {config.yml location} {delete_indices.yml location} >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that `alias` created by you `filebeat` is not pointing to index which you want to delete as high-lighted in exception message.

> index.lifecycle.rollover_alias [filebeat]  does not point to index
> [filebeat-log-centralization-ds-test-2020.08.09]

You can use the [GET alias API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-alias.html) to confirm that and if not link [use update alias API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html) to link your `filebeat` alias to your `filebeat-log-centralization-ds-test-2020.08.09`.

Comment: Trying to add this alias to the template results in the following error:
```illegal_argument_exception: Rollover alias [filebeat] can point to multiple indices, found duplicated alias [[filebeat]] in index template [filebeat-template]```

Comment: @Tomer.Ov, can you provide the get alias API output for `filebeat` alias?